# bash if string does not contain multiple entries

Tags: bash

In bash, I need to check to see if a string does not contain a list of values.  And if it does not then add it to an array

```sh
if [[ $x != *"Tom"* ]] || [[ $x != *"Dick"* ]]  || [[ $x != *"Harry"* ]] || [[ $x != *"Bob"* ]]; then
    echo $x
    files_to_transfer+=( $x )
fi
```

I need the variable to be added to the array if it does not contain either Tom, Dick, Harry or Bob.

When I run this, every file gets added to my array even the ones with Tom, Dick, Harry or Bob in the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
[[ $x != *Tom* && $x != *Dick* && $x != *Harry* && $x != *Bob* ]]
```

i.e. you need to add it when it contains none of them, not if it doesn't contain one of them.

Also, you can use Boolean operators inside `[[ ... ]]`; and there's no need to double quote letters, as they have no special meaning.